# Compute the following integral (moments and the log normal distribution).

Tags: calculus, integration, probability-theory

> Let $X \sim \log N(0,1)$. Then, $f_X(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}x}e^{-\frac12(\log(x))^2}$. I want to prove that for $k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$
> $$\int_0^\infty x^k \sin(2 \pi \log(x))f_X(x) dx = 0.$$

I found the hint from [here](http://www.stat.uchicago.edu/%7Epmcc/courses/stat306/2013/cumulants.pdf) that I first need to replace the variable $\log(x)$ by $y+k$. Then, with some computation, the integral is equal to
$$\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \sin(2 \pi (y + k)) e^{-\frac12(y^2-k^2)} dy.$$

I am not sure what step should be followed. Can you give some hint?

Comment: Integrand is an odd function. Take the integral over symmetric intervals $[-n,n]$ (which is 0) and use absolute convergence to pass to the limit.

Comment: Note in particular that @openspace's use of the sine function's periodicity to obtain an odd integrand explains why the constraint $k\in\Bbb Z$ (the ${}^+$ is actually unnecessary) exists in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint 1*

$$\sin(2\pi (y+k)) = \sin(2\pi y)$$

*Hint 2*
$\sin(x)$ iss odd function
$$\sin(2\pi y) = -\sin(2\pi (-y))$$

Now what about integral over line of odd function?